# Javac isn't recognized as internal or external command

Tags: java, command, javac

javac command isn't recognized , although am sure that the path is correctly added to system variables , even though  java command works well and shows info 
am running windows 8 , x64bit
also tried "setpath" but still not working

Comment: Is the JDK installed? The JRE isn't sufficient for compiling Java.

Comment: Have you tried changing to the installation directory and executing the command directly?

Comment: Make sure you added jdk1.7.0_25/bin directory to your path. Although Windows 8 doesn't require that you restart your machine, you might want to give that a try anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason it was the JRE , because when I reinstalled it worked